# Possibility of decrypting pbkdf2_sha256 by bruteforce

Tags: encryption, sha256, pbkdf2

Is it theoretically possible to brute pbkdf2_sha256 type of hash if I make a dictionary which contains all possible passwords?

I mean, it's possible to kinda brute sha256 hash, but I haven't even heard of pbkdf2_sha256 thing.

Comment: There is a salt variable in the encryption method and if I'm right, there is absolutely no way giving decryption a shot if I have no this "salt" variable. Am I right?

Comment: You could examine how the algorithm works to find out more.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thats definitely what im going to do, i'd only like to know the chances beforehand